# Why does the function about getting current time return a wrong time point

Tags: c++, c++14, c++-chrono

I'm working with C++11 and I wrote a function to get the current time point:

```
template <typename T = std::chrono::milliseconds>
using Clock = std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, T>;

// get current time point
template <typename T = std::chrono::milliseconds>
inline Clock<T> getCurrentTimePoint(int8_t timeZone = 0) {
    return std::chrono::time_point_cast<T>(std::chrono::system_clock::now()) +
        std::chrono::hours {timezone};
}
```

However, I just tested the function and it gave me a very strange output.

```
auto now1 = std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now());
auto now2 = getCurrentTimePoint<std::chrono::seconds>();
LOG(INFO) << "debug - now1:" << now1.time_since_epoch().count() << " now2:" << now2.time_since_epoch().count();
```

`LOG(INFO)` can print stream into a log file. So in the log file, I got this:

```
debug - now1:1641294039 now2:1537614039
```

So, `now1` works as exptected but `now2` is really weird because its value is a time point of about three years ago, which is 22/09/2018.

However, I've tried to make a demo here: https://godbolt.org/z/ns3116e63 and it always gives me a correct result.

I'm really confused.

My machine is Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS. I'm using CMake to compile my project. I added `add_definitions(-std=c++14)` in the file `CMakeLists.txt`.

**Update**

I tested again the next day and here is the result.

I added two more functions, which are exactly the same except their names:

```
std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::seconds> getCurrentTimePoint1(int8_t timeZone = 0) {
    return std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now()) + std::chrono::hours {timeZone};
}

std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock, std::chrono::seconds> getCurrentTimePoint2(int8_t timeZone = 0) { // OK
    return std::chrono::time_point_cast<std::chrono::seconds>(std::chrono::system_clock::now()) + std::chrono::hours {timeZone};
}
```

`getCurrentTimePoint1` gave me the wrong result, just like `now2` above. But `getCurrentTimePoint2` gave me the correct result, just like `now1` above. This is really weird...

Then I added more functions, such as the function without parameter to do more tests. At some moment, `getCurrentTimePoint1` could generate a correct result too!

It seems that adding more functions returning `std::chrono::time_point` or calling these functions more times could solve this issue!

Comment: Hmm... weird. I could not reproduce the erroneous value on Windows with Clang and MSVC, neither in 32 nor in 64 bits mode.

Comment: @SergeBallesta Yeah, I'm so confused. My machine is a node of a cluster of web servers. The company has deployed some mechanism to synchronize the system time of each node. I don't know if this may cause such an issue. But on the other hand, `now1` works. So it seems that my function can't work as exptected...

Comment: I've seen this happening on some old chips and\or OS. (think 15 year old Intel CPU and Win7, or a 8 year old "grey" unlocked Intel CPU). Try repeat action  several in same program and see if it changes. It can be  non-compliant hardware , i.e.  inconsistent TSC frequency or unstable clock. SOme combinations of old hardware and OS assuming it's compliant one, inherently were giving wrong result first time after process start.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I just tryed repeatedly but it's not working. But you just remind me that I did meet such a case last week in another project: the time wasn't correct at the first time but after repeating several times, it worked. So, you are telling me if I use immediately `time(nullptr` or `now1`, it would work as exptected whereas if I add one more function like `getCurrentTimePoint`, it may not work as exptected?

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie I don't know hardware at all. But if it's a hardware issue, just like you said, inconsistent TSC frequency or unstable clock, so it means that such a kind of issue may cause an incorrect time point if developer just used a very simple function to wrap one single line? So use it immediately? OK. wrap it with a function and call the function? not OK. OMG... I just can't imagine how it could be like this.

Comment: @Yves I only traced that on Windows once and in that case it was that QueryPerformanceFrequency was returning wrong (either zero or too big, effectively negative) value first time called. In that case it was BIOS issue and never fixed one for particular system. Another case was easily fixed by replacing the battery of realtime clock, it was a Dell Optiflex workstation. I would advise to check drivers, BIOS updates, etc.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Check my update. For now I still don't know why but I think you are right.

Comment: Here also, as in your other questions: You have a typo: `timezone` -> `timeZone`. The `timezone` mistakenly used comes from https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tzset.3.html, apparently included through `#include<chrono>`. It is of type `long`, so convertible to a duration without error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, this is a very stupid mistake.

```
template <typename T = std::chrono::milliseconds>
inline Clock<T> getCurrentTimePoint(int8_t timeZone = 0) {
    return std::chrono::time_point_cast<T>(std::chrono::system_clock::now()) +
        std::chrono::hours {timezone}; // typo error! timeZone, instead of timezone
}
```

The variable `timezone` has been defined (man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tzset.3.html) and been included by `chrono`. That's why the compiler didn't generate any error.

Comment: slaps-forehead.  I didn't see that either.